# drawing image from localhost onto canvas in chrome

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am accessing an image from a folder in localhost.

Image loads correctly in img tag. But, when I try to draw that image onto canvas, it doesn't appear!

I have implemented it such that when image is dropped onto the canvas, it is drawn onto it and I draw it by getting the image from original source. When I drag again and again, then, after some attempts, it appears.

The functionality is working perfectly in Firefox and I.E.

This is the source of my image on localhost:

```
b.src = "http://localhost/casema...E/2780Chrysanthemum.jpg"

ctx1.drawImage(b, x2-15*z, y2-15*z, w1, h1 );
```

Comment: It does not help if you post a link to your localhost! We can't see it!

Comment: I guess you wrote some code. Can we see it?

Comment: Same happens when i give a link of some image from internet!

Comment: from your code it's not clear - what values contains in variables - b, x2,z,y2,w1,h1, add more code please =)

Comment: do you get any errors? Are you waiting for the image to load before trying to draw it to the canvas?

Comment: No, i don't wait for the image to load! And it works fine in firefox and I.E. and i have tried to use 'b.onload' as well but didn't work. b is an image object. x2,y2 are co-ordinates. w1,h1 are width and height.

Comment: before that i was accessing the image from browser cache and it was working perfect in chrome too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5, it not for sure that an image will  always load immediately, so you
need to make sure that the image has fully loaded beford you draw it. this code may help you :

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "path/to/your/image";
myImage.onload = function(){
      //context is the canvas context 
      context.drawImage(myImage,x,y,weight,height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a local HTML file on your computer? If so you need to add the parameter

--allow-file-access-from-files

when calling Chrome.

Comment: where should i use this parameter? I mean at what place in my code?

Comment: But i upload the file on server(localhost) and then access it from there! and doing many attempts it appears sometimes!

Comment: As you are running your HTML file from localhost then I don't know why it is intermittent. Running it not from a server and just as an HTML file on your computer you need to create a shortcut for Chrome, right click on shortcut, select properties find the application target for the short cut and add the parameter after chrome.exe leaving a space.For more details search the phrase and chrome on google